# Agent and overhead crane have different spaces in AnyLogic

Tags: anylogic

I have an overhead Crane placed in Main, and i want to use this crane to move agent which is placed in an another agent called as MyAgent. When i tried to do that it is giving me an error of different spaces.
Can anyone help me to remove this error.
[main window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EADLC.png)
[Myagent logic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UNFzR.png)

[error discription](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AiOfj.png)

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is to push your embedded agent into a flowchart on `Main` using an "Enter" block. This will force it to live on the space of Main. Once done, use the same trick to push it back into the space of the normal parent agent of it.

Else, you can play with `setEnvironment()` but this does not always work

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but since it was a sample model that i have uploaded here.In real i have to use multiple times move by crane option, entering and exiting the object can not be a good option in my situation. I rather place the whole flow chart in main and then encapsulates my flow chart to an agent. so the nodes always stays with the crane in main.